# Openerp 7 schedule function to create records in table

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I have this function named `populate_attendance_normal_shift`. I am going to use it to get populate one of the tables in my db and I am planning to run in it with openerp scheduler. But the thing is I don't have any idea how to do it just only with this function.

I have tested it as an onchange function with printing some values and up to that it is working really fine.
Now what I need is populate the table with those values. My function is as like this....

```
    def populate_attendance_normal_shift(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        #The function which will populate the Allowance Attendance Table. 
        #Either the person will work as a roster basis or normal hours, This is the table need to get populated.
       
        result = {'value': {}}
        all_emp_id=0
        all_emp_type=""

        gt_dt=cr.execute("""SELECT ap.id,
                                   ap.sign_in, 
                                   ap.sign_out,
                                   ap.reldate,
                                   ap.day_type,
                                   ap.sign_in2, 
                                   ap.sign_out2,
                                   
                                   emp.id,
                                   emp.employee_no,
                                   emp.category,
                                   emp.department_id,
                                   emp.gender,
                                   emp.comp_id,
                                   emp.departmnt_id,
                                   emp.division_id,
                                   emp.sec_id
                                   
                            FROM attendance_processed ap
                            INNER JOIN hr_employee emp
                            ON ap.employe_name = emp.id
                            WHERE ((TO_TIMESTAMP(ap.sign_out, 'HH24:MI')::TIME)>(TO_TIMESTAMP('18:00', 'HH24:MI')::TIME))
                            AND (((TO_TIMESTAMP(ap.sign_out, 'HH24:MI')::TIME)-(TO_TIMESTAMP('18:00', 'HH24:MI')::TIME))> INTERVAL '4 hour')
                            AND (to_date(ap.reldate, 'YY-MM-DD') >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '45 days')""")
        
        gt_dd=cr.fetchall()
        
        if gt_dd:
            i=0
            for n in gt_dd:
                
                all_att_id=n[0]
                all_sign_in=n[1].encode("utf-8")
                all_sign_out=n[2].encode("utf-8")
                all_date=n[3].encode("utf-8")
                all_day=n[4].encode("utf-8")
                all_sign_in2=n[5]
                all_sign_out2=n[6]
                all_emp_id=n[7]
                all_emp_no=n[8]
                all_emp_cat=n[9]
                all_emp_dept_id=n[10]
                all_emp_gen=n[11]
                all_emp_comp=n[12]
                all_emp_dept=n[13]
                all_emp_divi=n[14]
                all_emp_sec=n[15]
                #all_emp_sec_name=n[15]
                emp_obj=cr.execute("""select ec.name from hr_employee e, employee_category_rel ecr, hr_employee_category ec 
                                      where e.id = ecr.emp_id and ec.id = ecr.category_id and e.employee_no='%s' and ec.name = 'Roster' """%(all_emp_no))
               
                if emp_obj:
                    all_emp_type="Roster"
                else:
                    all_emp_type="Normal"
                    
              
                cat_id = self.pool.get('hr.category').browse(cr, uid, all_emp_cat, context=None).priority
                
                
                
                chk_id=cr.execute("""SELECT id FROM allowance_attendances WHERE attendance_id=%d"""%(all_att_id))
        
                
                if not chk_id:
                   
                   print "^^^^^ This is where I checked the values^^^^^"
                   print all_att_id#
                   print all_sign_in#                 
                   print all_sign_out#
                   print all_date#                 
                   print all_day#
                   
                   print all_emp_id
                   print all_emp_no                 
                   print all_emp_cat
                   print all_emp_dept_id                 
                   print all_emp_comp
                   print all_emp_dept                 
                   print all_emp_divi
                   print all_emp_sec 
                   print all_emp_type
                   print cat_id

                  
                   
                   if (all_sign_in and all_sign_out)or(all_sign_in2 and all_sign_out2):
#                         self.get_number_of_hours(cr, uid, ids, all_date, all_sign_in, all_sign_out,all_sign_in2,all_sign_out2, all_emp_type, context)
             print "###### This is where I don't know how to do it#######"

#                         result['value']['employee_id'] =all_emp_id
#                         result['value']['catagory_id'] =cat_id
#                         result['value']['attendance_id'] =all_att_id
#                         result['value']['date'] =all_date
#                         result['value']['day'] =all_day
 #                       result['value'][''] =comp_hours
#                         result['value']['extra_hours'] =comp_hours
#                         result['value']['extra_hours'] =comp_hours
#                         result['value']['extra_hours'] =comp_hours
#                         result['value']['extra_hours'] =comp_hours
#                         result['value']['extra_hours'] =comp_hours
#                         result['value']['extra_hours'] =comp_hours
#                         result['value']['extra_hours'] =comp_hours
                        test_id=self.create(cr, uid, {
                                'employee_id':all_emp_id,
                                'catagory_id':cat_id,
                                'attendance_id':all_att_id, 
                                'date':all_date, 
                                #'day' :all_day
                                 })
                       
                #def write / update kathawa liyanna
                else:
                    print "Next part coming soon"
                


        return True
```

Comment: You can create cron for that.

Comment: Yep Scheduler is also working like a cron job but the thing is I want to know , without calling the Create function and PGSQL statements, is there a way in Openerp to create new records in tables ?

Comment: Why without create method?